# NHibernate 3 + Transaction Deadlocks (S#arp Architecture)

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2008, deadlock, s#arp-architecture

I appear to be getting a lot of random deadlocks when reading data from one of my tables. This table contains alot of information and is very frequently read and updated.

I am using S#arp Architechture 1.9 which uses the Transaction attribute on all my data access / update code.

Is there anything special which I need to do to ensure I don't get deadlocks, Should i update / read my data in a certain way.

Not too sure where to start on this one.

NHibernate 3
S#arpArchitecture 1.9
SQL Server 2008 R2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting actual deadlocks or blocked reads? If it is the former, consider rebuilding indexes and statistics.

Comment: I fixed this by running the sql server tuning advisor after running the profiler. It removed some of my indexes and created new ones which helped lots. I also enabled snapshot isolation which seemed to help also.